# C# The process cannot access file 'XYZ' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, html, streamwriter, process.start

I am been fighting with this problem the last couple of days, it works fine when I am on my dev machine, but on the client it is showing this error.

Now this is the code that I have that seems to be showing the error so any help or guidance would be amazing, thank you in advance.

```
 private void document()
 {
         StreamWriter sWrite = new StreamWriter("C:\\Demo\\index.html");
         //LOTS OF SWRITE LINES HERE
         sWrite.Close();
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Demo\\index.html");
 }
```

So I have no idea what it keeps telling me the file is already being used by another process if I run this method twice.

Comment: try wrapping the `StreamWriter code` around a `using(  ) {}`

Comment: a) Can you give the stack trace of the exception? b) Are you sure that there's never an exception happening in the method? c) Can this be called from multiple threads?

Comment: @VBenavides, try the code in the posted answer and test it both ways on the target server.. one with the `Flush()` code commented out and the other with the `Flush()` code uncommented.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I will try it now!

Comment: If you're running in a multithreaded environment keep in mind that you'll have to use some kind of lock to prevent a race condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of it depends on the exact behavior. This could be for a few reasons: it could be, for example, due to an exception. The following code will produce the exception you've described.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            const string path = @"[path].xml";

            try
            {
                // After the first exception, this call will start throwing
                // an exception to the effect that the file is in use
                StreamWriter sWrite = new StreamWriter(path, true);

                // The first time I run this exception will be raised
                throw new Exception();

                // Close will never get called and now I'll get an exception saying that the file is still in use
                // when I try to open it again. That's because the file lock was never released due to the exception
                sWrite.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
                //LOTS OF SWRITE LINES HERE

            Process.Start(path);
        }
```

A "using" block will fix this because it's equivalent to:

```
try
{
   //...
}
finally
{
   stream.Dispose();
}
```

In the context of your code, if you're doing a whole bunch of line writes it actually *does* make sense to consider if (and when) you want to call Flush at some point. The question is whether the write should be "all or none" - i.e. if an exception occurs, do you want the previous lines to still be written? If not, just use a "using" block - it'll call "Flush" once at the end in the "Dispose." Otherwise, you can call "Flush" earlier. For example:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(...))
{
    sw.WriteLine("your content");
    // A bunch of writes
    // Commit everything we've written so far to disc
    // ONLY do this if you could stop writing at this point and have the file be in a valid state.
    sw.Flush();

   sw.WriteLine("more content");
   // More writes
} // Now the using calls Dispose(), which calls Flush() again
```

A big possible bug is if you're doing this on multiple threads (especially if you're doing a lot of writes). If one thread calls your method and starts writing to the file, and then another thread calls it too and tries to start writing to the file as well, the second thread's call will fail because the first thread's still using the file. If this is the case, you'll need to use some kind of lock to make sure that the threads "take turns" writing to the file.

Answer (score 2):

here is what you can do for example before trying to open the file from the Process.Start

```
var path = @"C:\Demo\index.html";
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    sw.WriteLine("Your contents to be written go here");
}
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

Comment: `using handles the auto-disposing of the created objects` `flush` writes immediately to the file.. read up on `using and Flush()` method

Comment: Dispose calls Flush already for StreamWriter so it's not necessary to have both a "using" block and a call to "flush."

Comment: I'm not asking why "using" - that's perfectly sensible. My question is why you call "flush" - in the context of the code sample provided it's unnecessary given that Dispose() will already call it.

Comment: I second @EJoshuaS 's question / comment : `Flush` is not necessary in that context since `Using` will call `Dispose`, which will in turn call `Flush`, effectively making the call to `Flush` redundant.

Comment: I have run into situations on a daily basis where things work perfectly normal on a local machine and once on a Server the file already in use error happens, the reason I put the flush in is because you cannot assume that the object will be disposed of immediately nor can you assume that all the contents will be implicitly flushed .. the op can test it with the Flush() or commenting out the flush.. I use flush because of experience with not relying on assumptions

Comment: what if the OP were writing to a file in a for loop or a while loop.. and wanted to show the end user realtime the contents were written to the exact file..? then perhaps you would understand the need to use Flush.. because why wait for the full contents to finish writing ...?

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I will try it now!

Comment: I am trying it right now on the client computer, just changed the FileMode.Append for FileMode.Create as I dont want to end up with a huge file, I need a new one created everytime I create it.

Comment: yes you can change the code to fit your use case.. let me know how things pan out.. thanks

Comment: Client is testing the software so far without hiccups, I tried it both way with and without the flush, both seem to work fine, will have a final answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: sounds good @V.Benavides this is why I suggested to try it both ways you can always comment out the Flush() in the Answer I provided.. glad you were able to get this back up and running

Comment: Yeah, I used the streamwriter to create a html file because I created a very unique and personalized "report", I tried creating it on word but it was a huge mess, so writing an html file line by line and giving it looks with a preinstalled css3 file gave me the look I needed for the client. Thank you guys a lot.

Comment: After trying it for over 5 days, the code is not presenting any issues on any of the ways with and without the flush()

Comment: @V.Benavides sounds good.. just as I have suggested in my Posted Answer.. so I will update the answer to remove the `Flush()` if this works then mark it as the acceptable answer.. thanks